# Copy files with widestring path in C++

Tags: c++, file-io, widestring

I'm having some trouble using  wchar_t* strings for copying a file, how do I open them in C/C++ 
I need to use wide chars because the filenames are in unicode with different foreign languages.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You need to distinguish between unicode file *names*, and unicode file *content*. Unfortunately, standard C/C++ only deals with wchar_t for file content. Using wchar_t for file names is platform-specific (hence Brian Bondy's question for clarification).

On Windows, you have to use Microsoft-specific API (such as [`_wfopen`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yeby3zcb(VS.80).aspx)) to open a file with a wchar_t name. On all other systems, you need to use char as the data type for file names.